# Parsing and editing JSON in Groovy without slurper (LinkedHashMaps and ArrayLists)

Tags: json, jenkins, groovy, yaml

I set up Jenkins to read all the parameters from a YAML file, modifications to JSON configuration files included. In that Jenkins setup I can't use JSONslurper since I'm not admin.

In my YAML file I record only the values that should be updated and ended writing a function like this to merge the JSON code as extracted with `readJSON file: path/to/file.json returnPojo: true` (luckily, "Pipeline Utility Steps" is installed) and the LinkedHashMap representation of the YAML configuration.

This recursive function, mostly copied from the web, is the most I could get with my poor Java skills:

```
Map mergeMaps(... maps) {
    Map result = [:]
    maps.each { map ->
        if (map instanceof ArrayList) {
            map.each { submap ->
                submap.each { k, v ->
                    result[k] = result[k] instanceof Map || result[k] instanceof ArrayList ? this.mergeMaps(result[k], v) : v
                }
            }
        } else {
            map.each { k, v ->
                result[k] = result[k] instanceof Map || result[k] instanceof ArrayList ? this.mergeMaps(result[k], v) : v
            }
        }
    }
    result
}
```

The YAML section is as follows:

```
Serilog:
  WriteTo:
    - Name: File
      Args:
        path: /some/new/path/to/a/logfile.log
```

and the JSON configuration file contains this:

```
{
    [...]
    "Serilog":     {
        "Using": ["Serilog.Sinks.File"],
        "MinimumLevel": "Information",
        "Filter": [        {
            "Name": "ByExcluding",
            "Args": {"expression": "SourceContext = 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost'"}
        }],
        "WriteTo": [        {
            "Name": "File",
            "Args":             {
                "path": "path/to/a/logfile.log",
                "rollingInterval": "Day",
                "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
                "fileSizeLimitBytes": 5000000
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

As you can see I simply entered the ArrayList and skipped something when the parameter is ArrayList and this makes the output miss the square brackets after `"WriteTo":`.

I really can't guess how this works: I pass 2 maps as parameters, then the code cycles. But cycles WHAT? It runs 2 different threads for each map? How is the output harvested in the `result` variable? How are the two maps put in relationship one with the other?

Nevertheless it's near to work. Is there someone who can give some advice and clarify how this works?

Thanks!

Hoping someone will shed some light on this tangle and helps to achieve my goal.

Edit: this kind of "works" but it doesn't limit to output a merged Map: it seems to also change the input variables values like if the lhs and rhs variables were passed "by reference"; if there aren't smarter solutions I can live with this:

```
Map mergeMaps(lhs, rhs) {

    if (lhs in ArrayList) {
        rhs.eachWithIndex { elem, idx ->
            lhs[idx] = (lhs[idx] in Map ? mergeMaps(lhs[idx], rhs[idx]) : lhs[idx])
        }
    } else {
        rhs.each { k, v ->
            lhs[k] = (lhs[k] in Map || lhs[k] in ArrayList ? mergeMaps(lhs[k], v) : v)
        }
    }
    lhs
}
```

Comment: "how this works?" - your question is too wide.  the "goal" is not defined... please ask question(s) that are answerable.

Comment: I thought my question was clear: "I pass 2 maps as parameters, then the code cycles. But cycles WHAT? It runs 2 different threads for each map? How is the output harvested in the result variable? How are the two maps put in relationship one with the other?"

Answer (score 1):

You just want the non-mutating equivalent of your second algorithm:

```
def mergeMaps(lhs, rhs) {
    if (lhs in ArrayList) {
        rhs.indices.collect { idx ->
            lhs[idx] in Map ? mergeMaps(lhs[idx], rhs[idx]) : lhs[idx]
        }
    } else {
        lhs.collectEntries { k, v ->
            def newV = rhs[k] ?: v
            [k, (v in Map || v in ArrayList ? mergeMaps(v, newV) : newV)]
        }
    }
}
```